# TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded invalid read

Tags: c++, sdl, valgrind, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

When using the [Hans Kendrick](http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/hans-kendrick) font with `SDL2_ttf`;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

// Very shortened for demo purposes
int main () {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) { return 1; }
    if (TTF_Init() == -1) { return 1; }

    TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont("font.ttf", 28);

    if (font == NULL) { return 1; }

    SDL_Color blank = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    SDL_Color colour = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded(font, "Y", colour, blank);
}
```

`valgrind` reports an error;

```
==18109== Invalid read of size 1
==18109==    at 0x535812C: TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded (in /usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0.10.2)
==18109==    by 0x40080B: main (in /home/joshua/fontbug/test)
==18109==  Address 0xd9aaf4f is 1 bytes before a block of size 560 alloc'd
==18109==    at 0x4C28730: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18109==    by 0x4ED91FB: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.2.1)
==18109==    by 0x5357F00: TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded (in /usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0.10.2)
==18109==    by 0x40080B: main (in /home/joshua/fontbug/test)
```

and some systems crash. This depends on the characters (strings with a space at the front have never had this problem) and possibly the font size.

Using DejaVu does not have this problem.

**What is causing this, and how is it preventable?**

---

To build:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs) -lSDL2_ttf
```

Comment: Perhaps you should file an libsdl bug.

Comment: @n.m. Yup: https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2692

Answer (score 0):

I think (= not 100% sure) you must have a renderer before trying to render anything .
Why don't you try to use SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer
before using TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded ?